# How to read flat file and print a line every certain amount of records read - Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

Hello Spring Batch Community!

I'm reading a flat file which has a header and is mapped into headerPOJO, and a body (million records) which is mapped into bodyPOJO.

Input File:

```
01.01.2017|SUBDCOBR|12:21:23|01/12/2016|31/12/2016
01.01.2017|12345678231234|0002342434|BORGIA RUBEN|27-32548987-9|FA|A|2062-
00010443/444/445|142,12|30/08/2017|142,01
01.01.2017|12345673201234|2342434|ALVAREZ ESTHER|27-32533987-9|FA|A|2062-
00010443/444/445|142,12|30/08/2017|142,02
01.01.2017|12345673201234|0002342434|LOPEZ LUCRECIA|27-32553387-9|FA|A|2062-
00010443/444/445|142,12|30/08/2017|142,12
01.01.2017|12345672301234|0002342434|SILVA JESUS|27-32558657-9|NC|A|2062-
00010443|142,12|30/08/2017|142,12
.
.   
.
```

Specificaly, i need to print a formatted flat file with the following structure:

```
HEADER (8 customed lines, using data from HEADER input)
DETAILS (17 records from the body)
line break
SAME HEADER
DETAILS (next 17 records from the body)
line break
...
...  
...
REPEAT until EOF
```

I can't seem to understand how to achieve going from the FlatFileItemReader of the body and tell to print the header every 17 read lines. I tried doing a stepHeader and a stepBody , and generating ExitStatus.. but it always prints the same 17 first records or it just loops and never ends.  Please help!!

================== **UPDATE** ==================

What I did was... create a stepHeader and a stepBody . Each of them with their own reader, processor (business formatter) and writer.

The job will have only this 2 simple steps.

```
@Bean
public Job job() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(new JobListener())
            .start(stepHeader())
            .next(stepBody())
            .on("BACK TO STEPHEADER").to(stepHeader())
            .on("END").end().build()
            .build();
}
```

The header i read is configured with MaxItemCount=1, and mapped it to CabeceraFacturacion:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<CabeceraFacturacion> readerCabecera() throws Exception{

FlatFileItemReader<CabeceraFacturacion> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

reader.setLinesToSkip(0);
reader.setMaxItemCount(1);
reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/inputFiles/input.txt"));

DefaultLineMapper<CabeceraFacturacion> cabeceraLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|"); // en el default, la coma es el separador
tokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"printDate", "reportIdentifier", "tituloReporte", "fechaDesde", "fechaHasta"});

cabeceraLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
cabeceraLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new CabeceraFieldSetMapper());
cabeceraLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();

reader.setLineMapper(cabeceraLineMapper);

return reader;
}
```

The body i read it this way, skipping first line, and mapped it to DetalleFacturacion:

@Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader readerDetalleFacturacion(){

```
FlatFileItemReader<DetalleFacturacion> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
//reader.setMaxItemCount(17);
reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/inputFiles/input.txt"));

DefaultLineMapper<DetalleFacturacion> detalleLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizerDet = new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|"); // en el default, la coma es el separador
tokenizerDet.setNames(new String[] {"fechaEmision", "tipoDocumento", "letra", "nroComprobante",  
                            "nroCliente", "razonSocial", "cuit", "montoNetoGP", "montoNetoG3",
                            "montoExento", "impuestos", "montoTotal"});



detalleLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizerDet);
detalleLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new DetalleFieldSetMapper());
detalleLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();
reader.setLineMapper(detalleLineMapper);


return reader;
}
```

My Steps:

```
@Bean
public Step stepHeader() throws Exception {
   return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepHeader")
        .<CabeceraFacturacion, CabeceraFacturacion> chunk(17)
        .faultTolerant()
        .listener(new ChunkListener())
        .reader(readerCabecera())
        .writer(writerCabeceraFact())
        .allowStartIfComplete(true)
        .build();
}


@Bean
public Step stepBody() {
   return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepBody")
        .<DetalleFacturacion, DetalleFacturacion> chunk(17)
        .chunk(17)
        .faultTolerant()
        .listener(new ChunkListener())
        .reader(readerDetalleFacturacion())
        .writer(writerDetalleFact())
        .listener(new StepExecutionListener() {

            @Override
            public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
                if(stepExecution.getWriteCount()==17) {

                    return new ExitStatus("BACK TO STEPHEADER");                    
                };

//                      if(stepExecution.getReadCount()<17) {
//                          return new ExitStatus("END");                   

//                      }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {


            }


        })
        .allowStartIfComplete(true)
        .build();
}
```

1) I don't know how to achieve going back to the StepHeader indefinetely until the file ends. There i tried usind the stepExecution.getWriteCount(17).. but i'm not sure this is the right way to go.

2) i don´t know how to read 17 different records every time it loops ( i managed to make it loop but it would write the same first 17 records over and over again until i manually stopped the job. (I now know that loops are not recommended in Spring Batch processes)

3) if anyone has any idea on another way to achieve my goal, it will be most welcome.

4) Is there a way to make a decider that's "hearing" all the time, and sends the order to print header or body if certain condition is satisfied?

Up until now, the max i achieved is to read & write only one time the header... and in the next step read & write 17 lines of the body.

Comment: Well what have you tried?  Show your code.

Comment: Hello OldProgrammer! i did not want to overload the question with too much code from the start. There i made an update, thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you happen to know how can i read/write a file in a step, and when i reach 17 lines.. trigger the print of a header into the file, and then somehow go back to that same point of the step and continue reading/writing from where it left of.. until 17 lines are reached again.. and so on .. ?